# Create tar with same name as file but in different folder

Tags: linux, tar

I have multiple files in a folder. Is there any way to create individual tar file from each of these file with same name as file and save those tar files in different folder.

e.g suppose I have files 'file1', 'file2', 'file3' in a folder then I want to create tar files named 'file1.tar.gz', 'file2.tar.gz', 'file3.tar.gz' in some different folder.

Comment: It is best to ask such type of question on: http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run this simple shell script from inside your directory:

```
for file in *; do tar -czf $file.tar.gz $file; done
```

The result will be a new .tar.gz file for each one of the files inside the directory you're in.
If you wish to create the tar archives in another directory, just change the path that's right after the -cf flags. For example, if you wish to create the archives in another directory that's located in the same directory as your current one, write:

```
for file in *; do tar -czf ../<Other_Directory>/$file.tar.gz $file; done
```